# On adding an x-axis title to the waveform plot in LTSPICE

Tags: ltspice

I want to add a title to my x-axis in the waveform plot in LTSPICE. Do you know how? below is the snapshot:
[image]

Comment: not an electronics design question

Comment: Part of the design is report. jsotola you do not want to report your plot without title.

Comment: The way that you titled your plot is the best way

Comment: Hi Voltage Spike, I do not prefer to report using handwritten snipping tools. That is why I spent time to ask the question.

Comment: @Aria your question is about the use of software ... anyway, google can give you an answer in less than one minute

Comment: @jsotola If I found my answer in google I would not post my question here. If you are not interested in my questions maybe other engineers are interested. We should not give negative comments to a new contributor or even an old contributor if we are not interested. Maybe others are interested. If we do not want to help at least we can stop discourage the engineer who initiated a help request.

Comment: @jsotola's comment referred to the question, itself, not to the ability or willingness to answer. In this case, your question is already answered by the manual. Wouldn't you say it's far easier and much quicker to open it up and read it, instead of posting a question and waiting hours or more for an answer?

Comment: @Aria here is why I said that a web search yields an answer in less than a minute ... I searched `ltspice plot axis labels` ... https://duckduckgo.com/?q=ltspice+plot+axis+labels&ia=web ........... third hit is https://www.analog.com/en/technical-articles/ltspice-parametric-plots.html

Comment: @Aria `If I found my answer in google I would not post my question here` ... you said nothing about your struggle with searching ... also, many people go to SE first, without doing research

Answer (score 5, accepted):

LTSpice is not really designed to generate nice looking plots. There are usually no axis labels. My advice would be to export the data as text and draw the plot with some proper programm.

Despite this there is still a possibility to force LTSpice to generate a x-axis label. To do this you will have to add a second plot pane with another parameter on the x-axis. Then every x-axis will get a visible label. But these labels will be auto-generated and cannot be customized. It could look something like this:

[image: axis label]

In order to achieve this, follow these steps:

1. after simulation click the value you want to display in the schematic, e.g. I(R1)
2. right click in the graph and select 'Add Plot Pane'
3. right click in the new plot pane and select 'Add Traces', select also I(R1)
4. right click again and uncheck 'Sync. Horiz. Axes'
5. hover over the plot towards the x-axis of the upper pane until the cursor changes
6. right click and change 'Quantity Plotted:' to V(DC)

Now the plots should look like the ones above. You can customize things a little bit more by adding text, arrows, lines, boxes and so on. These can be found in 'Plot Settings' under 'Notes & Annotations'.

Comment: Thank you mais. On the step 5 I see a yellow ruler. Then I right click. When I type VDC for step 6, for quantity plotted, I get an error for the undefined symbol V(DC)

Comment: You need to add a label called 'DC' to your schematic (can also be another name).

Comment: Thanks mias, would you please tell me how to add a label to the schematic?

Comment: @mais There's no need to add another plot pane, renaming `time` can be done with one single plot, too (as long as it's a known quantity, as you correctly mention).

Comment: @Aria At this point you don't know how to use the tool and, thus, you resort to asking questions that can be answered by just about any tutorial out there. My recommendation would be to open up the manual and read it. Again, if you have to. If, after this, you still have questions about the basic usage, then it's time to use a tutorial. But all of these must be done if you intend to use the tool -- and, judging by your own comment in the OP, you need it for reports.

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen: any manual you recommend for me as a tutorial for LTSPICE?

Comment: @Aria If the manual (the official help that comes by pressing `F1`) doesn't do it for you (it is known to be rather spartan, but helpful), then I'd recommend going through [these links](http://ltwiki.org/index.php?title=SPICE_and_LTspice_Courseware_and_Tutorials). The Simon Bramble page is even mentioned in the official help, so I'd say it's worth it (though, I admit, I haven't checked it).